# send data from java to javascript using jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Totally a newbie for jsp. In my project, I need to send an arraylist / array from java to javascript.

This is my java code in jsp.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<% List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("one");
strList.add("two");
strList.add("three"); %>
```

in my javaScript, I want something like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var notes = ["one", "two", "three"];
});
```

So how do I send the data from java to javascript?  Please be specific. Thank you in advance.

---

solution from Bilal

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>

<html>
    <body>

    <% List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("one");
strList.add("two");
strList.add("three"); %>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    var notes = new Array();
    <%
    for(String note:strList){
    %>
    notes.push('<%=note%>');
    <%}%>
    alert(notes[0]);
});
</script>


</body>
```

Comment: I don't know whether i get your question completely, but just wanted to know that is the java script code is on the same jsp page? and you want you Arraylist values to use in the javascript code correct?

Comment: @Bilal Exactly.  The answer from Titus does not send the data from java to javascript.

Comment: Try this one not sure what you mean by sending <% List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("one");
strList.add("two");
strList.add("three"); %>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var notes = new Array();
 <%
    for(String note:strList){
 %>
 notes.push('<%=note%>');
 <%}%>
 alert(notes);
});
</script>

Comment: @Bilal StrList cannot be resolved to be a variable.  By the way, do you mind if you answer this in the answer session so I could accept your answer.  Thank you.

Comment: can you please share your jsp page so i can understand how you want to run that stuff.I also post a answer with the same code above

Comment: @Bilal sure thing.  I just uploaded the running code in my jsp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one to use java code in javascript block. I use this code in a jsp page which print the values notes array **one,two,three** not sure if you are looking for the same thing or something else.

```
<% List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    strList.add("one");
    strList.add("two");
    strList.add("three"); %>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var notes = new Array();
        <%
        for(String note:strList){
        %>
        notes.push('<%=note%>');
        <%}%>
        alert(notes);
    });
    </script>
```

this is my full jsp page code

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<% List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("one");
strList.add("two");
strList.add("three"); %>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var notes = new Array();
    <%
    for(String note:strList){
    %>
    notes.push('<%=note%>');
    <%}%>
    alert(notes);
});
</script>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I run it but it does not generate the alert for some reasons.

Comment: I edited the answer with my full jsp page which i just created for sample don't know whether you want the same stuff, but this code is running on my system and printing the values.

Comment: this is very helpful.  May I ask one question please? I want to make sure that notes has all the element, I try to traverse the notes array.  So i add "for each (var item in notes) {" right before alert() method, but it gives me error, i don't know why it does not let me write js code. Thank you

Comment: You can try this one for for each loop syntax please see some example on google var arrayLength = notes.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    alert(notes[i]);
 }

Comment: You can also use Firebug to see what is the error in your js code http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: you are absolutely right, but it does not make sense that I am allowed to write js code within <script>.  Oh nice, I will check that.  Thank you Bilal.

Answer (score 2):

On the client side, in the context in which the JavaScript code is executed, the Java code was already compiled, executed and converted to HTML, CSS or JavaScript. What you can do is to create some JavaScript code in your Java code.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<% List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
   strList.add("one");
   strList.add("two");
   strList.add("three"); 
   out.println("<script>");
   out.print("var notes = [");
   boolean first = true;
   for(String str: strList){
       out.print((first?"":",") + "\""+str+"\"");
       first = false;
   }
   out.print("];");
   out.println("alert(notes[0]);");
   out.println("</script>");
%>
```

The example above will create a new HTML `script` element which contains the definition and initialization of a JavaScript array which will contain all the `String`s from the `strList` list.

Another solution will be to use AJAX to connect to a `jsp` page from your JavaScript code to retrieve the data.

Comment: Thank you.  I am not sure if I have access to notes now. Right after your code, I use alert(notes[0]), but it does not generate an alert. And how do I really use this to initialize the notes? Thank you.

Comment: **use AJAX to connect to a jsp page from your JavaScript**

Comment: @vkosyj I've edited my answer to include a `alert(notes[0])` call. What my example does is to generate some HTML code. The `out.print(...)` and `out.println(...)` calls are just writing some text in the resulting HTML file that will be generated.

Comment: @Titus Thank you for your help. Sorry if i bother you again.  My question is that is there a way to actually put the all the elements in the strList in the array in javascript, say, var arr = ["one", "two", "three"]; Also when i run your code, i saw result in the console, how do i see the result in a html? Thank you.

Comment: @vkosyj Oh, I think it doesn't work because the page is not interpreted as a HTML page, you can add this `<%@page contentType="text/html";%>` to specify the page type.

Comment: @Titus Thank you for the reply, but it still does not generate html. hmmmm, let's me do some research on this.